# C#.net datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

How to add child rows in datagrid c#.net windows forms?

Comment: Are you asking about databinding?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you want to append rows you're easiest way is to append them to whatever DataSource you're using before you DataBind()

If this wasn't what you're after, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you bind the datagrid to a dataset. Could you please clarify what you are looking for so that we can get into more detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
DataGridView myGridView = new DataGridView();
myGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //This adds the new row
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a nested table, you'll have to go with a third-party control.  The DataGridView doesn't support it.

Comment: It's not pretty, but you can nest: you create a templateField column in your datagridview, edit the template and put a gridview inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly sure your data GridView name and create DataTable

```
DataTable DT= new DataTable();
```

then also create DataRow

```
DataRow row = new DataRow();
```

and last call the  add() function Like this:

```
 DT.Rows.Add("ID","Name","Addr","number");
```

and don't miss to set source on DataGrideView for Showing data :

```
DataGrideView.DataSource = DT;
```